# Changed a MouseOver ToolTip to OnClick, But wondering how to add a close button or AutoClose?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jquery-ui-tooltip

Changed a `MouseOver` ToolTip to `OnClick`, But wondering how to add a close button or AutoClose to the ToolTip.

Like the tooltip closes after a click on the close button or autoclose after the other tooltip is opened!

Can it be done?

Here is the code!

```
var htmltooltip={
tipclass: 'htmltooltip',
fadeeffect: [true, 500],
anchors: [],
tooltips: [], //array to contain references to all tooltip DIVs on the page

positiontip:function($, tipindex, e){
    var anchor=this.anchors[tipindex]
    var tooltip=this.tooltips[tipindex]
    var scrollLeft=window.pageXOffset? window.pageXOffset : this.iebody.scrollLeft
    var scrollTop=window.pageYOffset? window.pageYOffset : this.iebody.scrollTop
    var docwidth=(window.innerWidth)? window.innerWidth-15 : htmltooltip.iebody.clientWidth-15
    var docheight=(window.innerHeight)? window.innerHeight-18 : htmltooltip.iebody.clientHeight-15
    var tipx=anchor.dimensions.offsetx
    var tipy=anchor.dimensions.offsety+anchor.dimensions.h
    tipx=(tipx+tooltip.dimensions.w-scrollLeft>docwidth)? tipx-tooltip.dimensions.w : tipx //account for right edge
    tipy=(tipy+tooltip.dimensions.h-scrollTop>docheight)? tipy-tooltip.dimensions.h-anchor.dimensions.h : tipy //account for bottom edge
    $(tooltip).css({left: tipx, top: tipy})
},

showtip:function($, tipindex, e){
    var tooltip=this.tooltips[tipindex]
    if (this.fadeeffect[0])
        $(tooltip).hide().fadeIn(this.fadeeffect[1])
    else
        $(tooltip).show()
},

hidetip:function($, tipindex, e){
    var tooltip=this.tooltips[tipindex]
    if (this.fadeeffect[0])
        $(tooltip).fadeOut(this.fadeeffect[1])
    else
        $(tooltip).hide()   
},

updateanchordimensions:function($){
    var $anchors=$('*[@rel="'+htmltooltip.tipclass+'"]')
    $anchors.each(function(index){
        this.dimensions={w:this.offsetWidth, h:this.offsetHeight, offsetx:$(this).offset().left, offsety:$(this).offset().top}
    })
},

render:function(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        htmltooltip.iebody=(document.compatMode && document.compatMode!="BackCompat")? document.documentElement : document.body
        var $anchors=$('*[@rel="'+htmltooltip.tipclass+'"]')
        var $tooltips=$('div[@class="'+htmltooltip.tipclass+'"]')
        $anchors.each(function(index){ //find all links with "title=htmltooltip" declaration
            this.dimensions={w:this.offsetWidth, h:this.offsetHeight, offsetx:$(this).offset().left, offsety:$(this).offset().top} //store anchor dimensions
            this.tippos=index+' pos' //store index of corresponding tooltip
            var tooltip=$tooltips.eq(index).get(0) //ref corresponding tooltip
            if (tooltip==null) //if no corresponding tooltip found
                return //exist
            tooltip.dimensions={w:tooltip.offsetWidth, h:tooltip.offsetHeight}
            $(tooltip).remove().appendTo('body') //add tooltip to end of BODY for easier positioning
            htmltooltip.tooltips.push(tooltip) //store reference to each tooltip
            htmltooltip.anchors.push(this) //store reference to each anchor
            var $anchor=$(this)
            $anchor.click( 
        function(e){ //onMouseover element 
            htmltooltip.positiontip($, parseInt(this.tippos), e) 
            htmltooltip.showtip($, parseInt(this.tippos), e) 
        }
    ) 
            $(window).bind("resize", function(){htmltooltip.updateanchordimensions($)})
        })
    })
}
}

htmltooltip.render()
```

Comment: You could just trigger "open" on `click` and "close" on `mouseout` with a delay

Comment: Can you please ! Show me with the sample line of code how it needs to look like ! :) I'm not getting you

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to hide your tooltip on mouseout:

```
$anchor.mouseout(
            function(e){ 
                htmltooltip.hidetip($, parseInt(this.tippos), e) 
            }
        )
```